# Is Adderall Legal in China?

Tags: legal, health, china, drugs

I’ve been offered a position to teach English in China for a year, but of course I don’t want to do that without being able to take Adderall for my ADHD. The position I’ve been offered is in Shenzhen, which is apparently near Hong Kong, where I was told I might be able to get Adderall.

Comment: I didn't find Adderall or amphetamin on this site of prohibited drugs, but please wait for more conclusive answer. The list contains metamphetamin, though. Please try to contact Chinese doctors through your future employers! http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=LbwI3r665hnCf0cBo5ps9_pkOuYIuD5iXHc0XTvSkzwSs0k-D3psoiKZVSUrNF-MaZPCzQZ6qAOZtmHvvBvIVq

Comment: I have voted to leave open. While asked in a context more suitable for Expats SE, this question easily also applies to a mere traveler to China and certainly is not too broad.